# How to retrieve all keys from a dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, key, nsdictionary

How can I retrieve all the keys (only) from a NSDictionary? I do not need them in any particular order.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `allKeys` method on your `NSDictionary`.

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

`allKeys` : Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.

```
- (NSArray *)allKeys
```

Return Value

A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the dictionary has no entries.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to study the Dokumentation. ;-)
Take a look here:

[- (NSArray *)allKeys;](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

From the Dokumentation:

> Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.
>
> - (NSArray *)allKeys
>
> Return Value A new array containing the
>   dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the dictionary has no entries.
>
> Discussion The order of the elements in the array is not defined.