# Print keys of NSDictionary instead of values

Tags: ios, json, printing, nsdictionary, key

I download some content from a json webservice.

Is it possible print the keys and not the values instead? For the eventuality of not knowing what the keys are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve all keys from a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075304/how-to-retrieve-all-keys-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
for( NSString *aKey in [dictionary allKeys] )
{
    // do something like a log:
    NSLog(aKey);
}
```

OR

```
NSLog([dictionary allKeys]);
```

This should do the trick

Comment: or just `NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary allKeys])`

Comment: Or that, indeed. Depends on what he plans to do with it.

Comment: Thanks! It worked great! But it wont work if there is an array. For example {"postalcodes":[{"adminCode3":"70805","adminName2":"Politischer Bezirk Reutte","adminName3"}]}

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the NSDictionary's keyEnumerator method to get the keys, then you can loop through them and print them out.

Borrowing an example from Apple:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myDictionary keyEnumerator];
id key;

while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    NSLog(@"Do something with the key here:%@",key);
}
```